# Using regular expressions to read specific format

Tags: python, python-3.x

Having the following registry:

```
str = "RegName1,Regname2,0x00000000,0x100000"
```

I want to use a regular expression to get this values.

I try this but it doesn't work.

```
re.match('\s+,\s+,\d+,\d+',str)
```

Note: I want to ignore comments like `"//"`, `"#"`, etc..

Comment: In [`re.match`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.match) the regular expression is the first argument.

Comment: Sorry, I fixed it but it still doesn't work @khelwood

Comment: ```\s``` means whitespace. Perhaps you meant ```\w``` (word character)

Comment: Also `0x00000000` won't match ```\d+``` because `x` is not a digit.

Answer (score 0):

Identify your fields this way:

```
import re
text = "RegName1,Regname2,0x00000000,0x100000"
matches = re.match(r"(\w+),(\w+),(\w+),(\w+)", text)
```

Then, if you `print(matches)` and `print(matches[1])`, you'll get:

```
Python 3.6.1 (default, Dec 2015, 13:05:11)
[GCC 4.8.2] on linux

<_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(0, 37), match='RegName1,Regname2,0x00000000,0x100000'>
RegName1
```

Not sure how to avoid comment lines. But, at least they won't be matched by regex. For example:

```
text = "#Some comment"
matches = re.match(r"(\w+),(\w+),(\w+),(\w+)", text)
print(matches)
```

Throws:

```
Python 3.6.1 (default, Dec 2015, 13:05:11)
[GCC 4.8.2] on linux

None
```

So if you do:

```
if matches is not None:
    do something
```

..they will be avoided.